# Is it possible to pass parameters by reference using call_user_func_array()?

Tags: php, reference, callback

When using `call_user_func_array()` I want to pass a parameter by reference.  How would I do this.  For example

```
function toBeCalled( &$parameter ) {
    //...Do Something...
}

$changingVar = 'passThis';
$parameters = array( $changingVar );
call_user_func_array( 'toBeCalled', $parameters );
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

To pass by reference using `call_user_func_array()`, the parameter in the array must be a reference - it does not depend on the function definition whether or not it is passed by reference.  For example, this would work:

```
function toBeCalled( &$parameter ) {
    //...Do Something...
}

$changingVar = 'passThis';
$parameters = array( &$changingVar );
call_user_func_array( 'toBeCalled', $parameters );
```

See the notes on the [`call_user_func_array()` function documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) for more information.

Comment: This solution throws warning with STRICT enabled... "Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in"

Comment: I don't know about newer version of php but on my 5.3.3 server when i used `call_user_func("function", &$parameter)` I got the Deprecated message. When i switched to `call_user_func_array` it fixed the issue. So then i checked with STRICT enabled and still didn't get the message so i think this is an acceptable way to do it.

Comment: I made a code test, and I works for me from php 4.3.0 - 7.4.0 even if I enable STRICT. @see https://3v4l.org/NJN2u  to see by yourself

Answer (score 2):

Directly, it may be impossible -- however, if you have control both over the function you are implementing *and* of the code that *calls* it - then there is one work-around that you *might* find suitable.

Would you be okay with having to embed the variable in question into an object? The code would look (somewhat) like this if you did so.

```
function toBeCalled( $par_ref ) {
    $parameter = $par_ref->parameter;
    //...Do Something...
    $par_ref->parameter = $parameter;
}

$changingVar = 'passThis';
$parembed = new stdClass; // Creates an empty object
$parembed->parameter = array( $changingVar );
call_user_func_array( 'toBeCalled', $parembed );
```

You see, an object variable in PHP is merely a *reference* to the *contents* of the object --- so if you pass an object to a function, any changes that the function makes to the *content* of the object will be reflected in what the calling function has access to as well.

Just make sure that the calling function never does an assignment to the object variable *itself* - or that will cause the function to, basically, *lose* the reference. Any assignment statement the function makes must be *strictly* to the *contents* of the object.

Answer (score 0):

This works by double referencing,the original variable is modified when the $parameter variable is modified.

```
$a = 2;
$a = toBeCalled($a);
echo $a //50

function toBeCalled( &$par_ref ) {
    $parameter = &$par_ref;
    $parameter = $parameter*25;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Except you are using deprecated functionality here. You'll generate a warning in PHP5 making it less than perfect.

> Warning: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated; If you would like to pass it by reference, modify the declaration of runtime function name. If you would like to enable call-time pass-by-reference, you can set allow_call_time_pass_reference to true in your INI file in ...

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be any other option as far as I can discover.

Comment: I just tried doing this with PHP 5.2.9 and didn't get any warnings.  I think you might be confused by the fact that array() isn't really a function - what I'm doing in my code example is basically setting `$parameters[0] =& $changingVar`.  Therefore, it's not call-time pass-by-reference - the pass-by-reference is specified in the method signature.

Comment: That only applies to direct function calls.  `array()` isn't a function.  As of PHP 5.5, it's quite normal to put references in arrays.

Comment: Keep in mind that passing `new` by reference is deprecated with PHP 5.5(?), so `$foo =& new ReferenceObject` isn't allowed anymore.