# php5.3 - mysqli_stmt:bind_params with call_user_func_array warnings

Tags: mysqli, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to pass parameters by reference using call_user_func_array()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295016/is-it-possible-to-pass-parameters-by-reference-using-call-user-func-array)

I have the following line of code which worked in PHP 5.1, but isn't working in PHP 5.3.

```
$input = array('ss','john','programmer');
call_user_func_array(array($mysqli_stmt, 'bind_param'), $input);
```

In PHP 5.3, I get the following warning message:

> Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/startmission/em/class/cls.data_access_object.php on line 785

I changed the code to the following and it worked:

```
$a = 'johnl';
$b = 'programmer';
$mysqli_stmt->bind_param('ss',$a,$b);
```

I found this in the php documentation:

> Care must be taken when using mysqli_stmt_bind_param() in
>   conjunction with call_user_func_array(). Note that
>   mysqli_stmt_bind_param()  requires parameters to be passed by reference,
>   whereas call_user_func_array() can accept as a parameter a list of
>   variables that can represent references or values.

So my question is, how do I replicate the functionality of the call_user_func_array + bind_params such that i can dynamically bind variables at run time?

Comment: this is not a duplicate of the one linked to. this is specifically about call_user_func_array WITH mysqli. the linked to question has no relationship with mysqli at all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem in a user note by [*fabio at kidopi dot com dot br3 years ago* on the PHP manual page of `mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#96770) (slightly modified):

> I used to have problems with `call_user_func_array` and `bind_param` after migrating to php 5.3.
>
> The cause is that 5.3 requires array values as reference while 5.2 worked with real values (but also with references). So I created a secondary helper function to help me with this:
>
> ```
> function refValues($arr)
> { 
>         $refs = array();
>
>         foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
>         {
>             $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key]; 
>         }
>
>         return $refs; 
> }
> ```
>
> and changed my previous function from:
>
> ```
> call_user_func_array(array($this->stmt, "bind_param"), $this->values);
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> call_user_func_array(array($this->stmt, "bind_param"), refValues($this->values));
> ```
>
> This way my db functions keep working in PHP 5.2/5.3 servers.

Comment: This refValues function doesn't compile. It has number of curly braces mismatch... Can you fix it?

Comment: you need to add types first. $types = 'ss', array_unshift($input,$types); then above function will work prefectly. thank you john.