# PHP 5.5, can't get call_user_func_array to work with bing_param

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, call-user-func-array

I have PHP version 5.5.9-1 and having trouble with call_user_func_array and bind_param for stmt. I have the following code

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM studentTable WHERE firstname = ?";
if(!($stmt = $conn->prepare($query))){
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
    return;
}
$paramType= 's';
$paramValue= 'bob';
$a_params = array(&$paramType, &$paramValue);
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'),$a_params)
```

I am getting the following error and I don't know why

```
Binding parameters failed: (0)
```

I have tried wrapping the strings "'s'" but that reports that there is not enough arguments. What am i doing wrong?

Thank you

UPDATE

I have tried the code from [php5.3 - mysqli_stmt:bind_params with call_user_func_array warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681262/php5-3-mysqli-stmtbind-params-with-call-user-func-array-warnings) but still not working

Comment: why are you using call_user_func_array instead of calling bind_param on the the stmt directly?

Comment: I want to dynamically add bindings, just trying to get example working

Comment: [Your code basically works](https://3v4l.org/EHOk2), are you 100% sure the error does not come from somewhere else ? Might it be possible, your error is not even an error? The way you check for an error is wrong I guess, because you don't check typesafe.

Comment: This code lacks a verifiable example and a reliable error message as well

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem (I just don't remember exactly what problem it was), I've solved this situation using [ReflectionMethod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php).

```
$type = 's';
$parameter = 'bob';

$values = [$type , &$parameter];

$reflectionMethod = new \ReflectionMethod($statement , 'bind_param');
$reflectionMethod->invokeArgs($statement , $values);

$statement->execute();
```

The code above comes from a [simple study case](https://bitbucket.org/harbingerproject/database/src/5965884dfb395fbe22b4facdaeaf0c7273188588/Statement/MySQLiStatement.php?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#MySQLiStatement.php-150) of my own. Created with PHP 5.5 and tested with PHP 7 (a long time ago...) on Debian Jessie.

After all, your code should work as well. With reflection, this code does the same thing as your code.

Ps.: as you can read in comments below, it slower than call_user_func_array and should be avoided in production.

Comment: Reflection in PHP is slow and should be avoided in production, Daniel's approach should work

Comment: @DanFromGermany I agree with you, as a study case, it's just another possibility.