# why pass-by-reference doesn't change the value of a variable?

Tags: php, reference, pass-by-reference

```
$string='string';
function change(&$str){
    $str='str';
}
call_user_func('change',$string);
echo $string;
```

output is 'string'. but $str refer to the $string , so change in $str should also change $string? why the value is still same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with `call_user_func()`:

From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php):

> Note that the parameters for call_user_func() are not passed by reference.

That said you still can use [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php). Using the reference becomes now possible. Here's the code you want:

```
function change(&$str)
{
    $str='str';
}

$string='string';
$parameters = array(&$string);
call_user_func_array('change',$parameters);
echo $string;
```

However this solution is now Deprecated.

You still can get rid of `call_user_func()`, and simply do:

```
function change(&$str)
{
    $str='str';
}

$string='string';
change($string);
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

It clearly mention that **the parameters for call_user_func() are not passed by reference.**

Answer (score 1):

**`call_user_func` doesn't pass by reference**. From [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php):

> Note that the parameters for call_user_func() are not passed by reference.

(`change($string)`, on the other hand, gives `"str"` as you would expect).

Further reading: [Why does PHP's call_user_func() function not support passing by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259713/why-does-phps-call-user-func-function-not-support-passing-by-reference?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Here's your error message:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Parameter 1 to change() expected to be a reference, value given on line <b>5</b>
```

because `call_user_func` does not pass parameters by reference.

Try run it like this:

```
$string='string';
function change(&$str){
    $str='str';
}
change($string);
echo $string;
```