# PHP callback using a reference

Tags: php, reference, callback

I have:

```
function increment(&$var)
{
    $var++;
}

$a = 0;
call_user_func('increment', $a);
echo $a."\n";
```

Why does this return:

```
Warning: Parameter 1 to increment() expected to be a reference, value given in
```

and $a is still 0. Why is this?

Any references to official documentation would help.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259713/why-does-phps-call-user-func-function-not-support-passing-by-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) says "Note: Note that the parameters for call_user_func() are not passed by reference."

You might use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) instead.

```
function increment(&$a) {
    $a++;
}

$x = 1;

call_user_func_array("increment", array(&$x));

echo $x;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of **[call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)**:

> Calls the callback given by the first parameter and passes the remaining parameters as arguments.

This is what you want using **[call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)** instead of **[call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)**:

```
<?php
function increment(&$var)
{
    $var++;
}

$a = 0;
call_user_func_array("increment", array(&$a));
echo $a."\n";
```