# Variable Reference as Function Argument

Tags: php, zend-framework, reference, function-pointers, helper

All about a Zend Application with an action helper.

**I want to unset some pairs of an array by a function.**

`helper:`

```
class Application_Controller_Action_Helper_TestHelper extends Zend_Contr[...]
{    
    public function direct(&$array)
    {
        if(isset($array['key']))
            unset($array['key']);
    }
}
```

`controller:`

```
$this->_helper->TestHelper($var);
```

**How could I get it working?**

Comment: Your example of pass-by-ref should be working already. Isn't it? Please, explain the behavior you're getting...

Comment: In my application I want the helper to unset some pairs of the array (parameter). It looks like:
`public function direct(&$array){ if(isset($array['controller'])) unset($array['controller']); }`
There is no error and no warning but the array is exactly the same like before.

Comment: I think the example you've given under "What I want is this" should work perfectly fine except that the left-hand side of the assignment `var = $var + 1` should read `$var` instead of just `var`

Comment: @sharethis That's weird... Are you sure? Did you try `print_r()` the $array passed before and after the call to `direct()` to check? Could it be that, for example, the wrong key is being used in the `isset()` call in your real code? That would make it seem that the array isn't changing... (I tested the function you posted here, and for me the array changed.)

Comment: @eljunior By testing i noticed that unset() unsets only the referenced array and not the real one.
(_updated the main post with arrays_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must also *pass it as reference*:
`$this->_helper->TestHelper(&$var);`

**UPDATE:**
Ups, I had my errors turned off. You (and now me) are getting the error [because...](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

> There is no reference sign on a function call - only on function
>   definitions. Function definitions alone are enough to correctly pass
>   the argument by reference. As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning
>   saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use &
>   in foo(&$a);.

ZF's HelperBroker uses `return call_user_func_array(array($helper, 'direct'), $args);` to call your direct() method. Check the [docs](http://www.php.net/call_user_func_array), but it seems `call_user_func_array` passes by reference, although with several quirks.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295016/is-it-possible-to-pass-parameters-by-reference-using-call-user-func-array).

Comment: Ohh, one problem: I get `Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated` Why??

Comment: That means I have to call like this?  `$var = &$paramter; $this->_helper->TestHelper($var);`

Answer (score 2):

Since you are now passing by reference, you can modify the variable in the method and the changes will be applied to the original variable. However, the way you have it now you are not changing the variable at all, just returning the result of the expression, like in your first example. You should have something like this instead:

```
class Application_Controller_Action_Helper_TestHelper extends Zend_Contr[...] {
    public function direct(&$var) {
        $var = $var + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately just a typing error in my post but not in my code... ;-)