# Zend Framework: Pass by reference to view helper not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, pass-by-reference, view-helpers

Here is a simple view helper (notice the pass-by-reference argument):

```
class Zend_View_Helper_MyViewHelper extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
  public function MyViewHelper(&$array)
  {
    unset($array['someExistingKey']);
  }
}
```

This does not work in the view. `$array['someExistingKey']` is still set (except within the immediate context of the method). Zend must be doing something to prevent the array from being passed in by reference. Any ideas on a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just thought of a workaround. You just have to call the helper manually, instead of letting ZF call it through `call_user_func_array`.

**Ref.php**

```
class Zend_View_Helper_Ref extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function removeFromRef(&$ref)
    {
        // change your var value here
        unset($ref['key']);
    }

    /**
     * ZF calls this for us, but we'll call what we want, so you can skip this.
     */
//    public function ref()
//    {}
}
```

As you can see, you can skip the convention of having to name your main method as the filename, but I still recommend it.
Now, you can pass references in views/controllers:

```
// in view:
$this->getHelper('Ref')->removeFromRef($someVar2Change);
// in controller
$this->view->getHelper('Ref')->removeFromRef($someVar2Change);
```

Basically, this is what `$this->ref()` does: gets the helper, then calls `call_user_func_array`.

Some people may have problems using `$this->getHelper('Ref')->ref()` instead of `$this->ref()` though, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `$this->MyViewHelper($array)` from your templates you are not actually calling the helper class directly, Zend_View is instantiating the class and calling it for you. So I think you might have trouble getting this working. Your best bet is probably to use Zend_Registry, or refactor to take a different approach not requiring a global.

Comment: That's very disappointing to discover, but understandable. (Btw, it's not really a "global" but I know what you mean.)

Comment: See Zend_View_Abstract::_call(). It uses `call_user_func_array` to call your helper class. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369851/variable-reference-as-function-argument/8370652#8370652).