# array_pop() requires deprecated call-by-reference when invoked from call_user_func()

Tags: php, php-5.3

```
call_user_func('array_pop', $myarray);
```

gives 'Parameter 1 to array_pop() expected to be a reference, value given', while

```
call_user_func('array_pop', &$myarray);
```

gives 'Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated'.

So what am I supposed to do? I am on "PHP Version 5.3.5" on Windows, and turning of deprecated warnings isn't an option.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this serves as a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295016/is-it-possible-to-pass-parameters-by-reference-using-call-user-func-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either just call it directly:

```
array_pop($myarray);
```

Or use `call_user_func_array()`, which accepts an array of references as parameters without yelling at you about call-time pass-by-reference:

```
call_user_func_array('array_pop', array(&$myarray));
```

The reason this doesn't raise a warning about call-time pass-by-reference is because nothing of that sort actually happens. There is a subtle difference between [passing a variable by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) and creating an array of references and passing *that array* by value.

Comment: Thanks! I actually read that answer in some google result, but i failed to see that call_user_func was replaced with call_user_func_ARRAY and so i thought that i would have to change my function to nwrap the array (which wouln't be possible in my case, since i was using array_pop).